# Help on my way for landscape that works on linux (for mac and windows)

Tags: landscape

I am a linux user and using the following way for landscape pages in my system:

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=4cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot[OE]{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\centering\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr 2cm-10pt}\end{minipage}}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\usepackage{adjustbox}


\newenvironment{myLandscape}
               {\clearpage                 
                \pdfpageattr{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}%
                \newgeometry{top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=4cm,right=2cm}% 
                \begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}%
                \begin{minipage}{\textheight}%
}
               {\end{minipage}% 
                \end{adjustbox}%
                \clearpage

                \pdfpageattr{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 0}%
                \restoregeometry
               }


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\section{Some Section}
\subsection{Some Subsection}
Some text in portrait here

\lipsum[1]


\begin{myLandscape}
  Test Text on Rotated Page.

  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{A centered 10cm figure}
  \end{center}  
\end{myLandscape}

Text in next page.

\end{document}
```

My problem is that the pdf generated by this code can not opened in a mac (and possibly in a windows OS) but skips the landscape pages [tested from friends with mac with both "adobe" (or acrobat or adobe acrobat) and the "preview" pdf readers].

I 'd like to change the code and make it work for all these OSs (linux, mac and Windows) but I have not a mac and not windows system too. So, I would like help from someone that can compile and test the code and help me with the additions needed to be able to use it on any OS.

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

PS: I know about `lscape` and `pdflscape` packages, but I need more control than these packages and to get over their problems on margins etc. (Every landscape page has to be in one environment with my way but this is not a problem for me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are writing `\the \pdfpageattr /Rotate 90` in the pdf, you must expand the value. The resetting code is wrong, the goal is not to add /Rotate 0 but to remove the /Rotate 90 (which happens in your code at the \end{myLandscape} automatically).

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=4cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot[OE]{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\centering\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr 2cm-10pt}\end{minipage}}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\usepackage{adjustbox}


\newenvironment{myLandscape}
               {\clearpage
                \pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}%
                \newgeometry{top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=4cm,right=2cm}%
                \begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}%
                \begin{minipage}{\textheight}%
}
               {\end{minipage}%
                \end{adjustbox}%
                \clearpage
                \restoregeometry
               }


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\section{Some Section}
\subsection{Some Subsection}
Some text in portrait here

\lipsum[1]


\begin{myLandscape}
  Test Text on Rotated Page.

  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{A centered 10cm figure}
  \end{center}
\end{myLandscape}

Text in next page.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ulrike... I would like to know if this works on mac or on windows for you (I suppose it was a mistake of mine and it will work anywhere... but have to ask before accepting)... Strange that my way worked for linux

Comment: it works on windows (while your code produced a broken pdf).

Comment: Thanks... I will ask from a friend with mac to test it and then will accept.