# Landscape oriented long tables with small margins

Tags: tables, longtable, pdflscape, sidewaystable

I want a long table to be landscape oriented with small margins (all margins).  I need the page number to be at the bottom of the page.

`\sidewaystable` works fine for a short table and does what I need.  I can use 
`\setlength\LTleft{-1in}` and `\setlength\LTright{-1in}` to increase the left and right margins, but this doesn't do anything to the top and bottom.  Also, sidewaystable does not stretch across pages and manually breaking them wasn't keeping the multiple tables together so they weren't following in the order I expect (I need to stay with floats and numbering etc.)

`\pdflscape` doesn't shift the page number to the new "bottom" of the page (the argument was that it was confusing to people if the page number moved, however print is rare now and so this is exactly what is happening with the pdf).

I tried `newgeometry` to move into the margins, but that didn't do anything to the page numbers so the left margin (in landscape mode) stays really large.  I tried adding `\thispagestyle{empty}` to the landscape mode, but it only changed one page - not the subsequent pages in the table, and the margin stayed large.

I've seen lots of related questions, but nothing recent and wondering if there is a solution to this now.  I am willing to sacrifice having page numbers entirely on these pages if that will fix things (but I'd rather keep them if they can show up at the bottom of the page rather than in the left margin).

```
\documentclass[11pt,paper=a4]{article}
\usepackage{longtable} % for 'longtable' environment
\usepackage{pdflscape} % for 'landscape' environment
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\newgeometry{left = 0.5cm, right = 0.5cm, top = 0.5cm, bottom = 0.5cm}
\begin{longtable}{ | p{10cm} | *{14}{c|} p{3cm}}
\hline\endhead  % header material
\hline\endfoot  % footer material
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris tempor vulputate tempor. Integer feugiat dui quis massa sollicitudin aliquet. Sed semper id urna a condimentum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus pulvinar auctor lectus, nec auctor lorem aliquet eget. Praesent eleifend mauris massa, bibendum blandit dolor faucibus vel. Proin convallis nisl non mauris semper viverra. Cras non est arcu. Aenean sed diam commodo, tempor purus eu, blandit ante. & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 &  11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & Ut eget urna massa. Sed at eros non eros interdum venenatis eget quis justo. Cras neque orci, semper eu augue ut, lobortis feugiat lectus. Proin at tincidunt elit. \\
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris tempor vulputate tempor. Integer feugiat dui quis massa sollicitudin aliquet. Sed semper id urna a condimentum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus pulvinar auctor lectus, nec auctor lorem aliquet eget. Praesent eleifend mauris massa, bibendum blandit dolor faucibus vel. Proin convallis nisl non mauris semper viverra. Cras non est arcu. Aenean sed diam commodo, tempor purus eu, blandit ante. & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 &  11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & Ut eget urna massa. Sed at eros non eros interdum venenatis eget quis justo. Cras neque orci, semper eu augue ut, lobortis feugiat lectus. Proin at tincidunt elit. \\
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris tempor vulputate tempor. Integer feugiat dui quis massa sollicitudin aliquet. Sed semper id urna a condimentum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus pulvinar auctor lectus, nec auctor lorem aliquet eget. Praesent eleifend mauris massa, bibendum blandit dolor faucibus vel. Proin convallis nisl non mauris semper viverra. Cras non est arcu. Aenean sed diam commodo, tempor purus eu, blandit ante. & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 &  11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & Ut eget urna massa. Sed at eros non eros interdum venenatis eget quis justo. Cras neque orci, semper eu augue ut, lobortis feugiat lectus. Proin at tincidunt elit. \\
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris tempor vulputate tempor. Integer feugiat dui quis massa sollicitudin aliquet. Sed semper id urna a condimentum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus pulvinar auctor lectus, nec auctor lorem aliquet eget. Praesent eleifend mauris massa, bibendum blandit dolor faucibus vel. Proin convallis nisl non mauris semper viverra. Cras non est arcu. Aenean sed diam commodo, tempor purus eu, blandit ante. & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 &  11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & Ut eget urna massa. Sed at eros non eros interdum venenatis eget quis justo. Cras neque orci, semper eu augue ut, lobortis feugiat lectus. Proin at tincidunt elit. \\
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris tempor vulputate tempor. Integer feugiat dui quis massa sollicitudin aliquet. Sed semper id urna a condimentum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus pulvinar auctor lectus, nec auctor lorem aliquet eget. Praesent eleifend mauris massa, bibendum blandit dolor faucibus vel. Proin convallis nisl non mauris semper viverra. Cras non est arcu. Aenean sed diam commodo, tempor purus eu, blandit ante. & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 &  11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & Ut eget urna massa. Sed at eros non eros interdum venenatis eget quis justo. Cras neque orci, semper eu augue ut, lobortis feugiat lectus. Proin at tincidunt elit. \\
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris tempor vulputate tempor. Integer feugiat dui quis massa sollicitudin aliquet. Sed semper id urna a condimentum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus pulvinar auctor lectus, nec auctor lorem aliquet eget. Praesent eleifend mauris massa, bibendum blandit dolor faucibus vel. Proin convallis nisl non mauris semper viverra. Cras non est arcu. Aenean sed diam commodo, tempor purus eu, blandit ante. & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 &  11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & Ut eget urna massa. Sed at eros non eros interdum venenatis eget quis justo. Cras neque orci, semper eu augue ut, lobortis feugiat lectus. Proin at tincidunt elit. \\
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris tempor vulputate tempor. Integer feugiat dui quis massa sollicitudin aliquet. Sed semper id urna a condimentum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus pulvinar auctor lectus, nec auctor lorem aliquet eget. Praesent eleifend mauris massa, bibendum blandit dolor faucibus vel. Proin convallis nisl non mauris semper viverra. Cras non est arcu. Aenean sed diam commodo, tempor purus eu, blandit ante. & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 &  11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & Ut eget urna massa. Sed at eros non eros interdum venenatis eget quis justo. Cras neque orci, semper eu augue ut, lobortis feugiat lectus. Proin at tincidunt elit. \\
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris tempor vulputate tempor. Integer feugiat dui quis massa sollicitudin aliquet. Sed semper id urna a condimentum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus pulvinar auctor lectus, nec auctor lorem aliquet eget. Praesent eleifend mauris massa, bibendum blandit dolor faucibus vel. Proin convallis nisl non mauris semper viverra. Cras non est arcu. Aenean sed diam commodo, tempor purus eu, blandit ante. & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 &  11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & Ut eget urna massa. Sed at eros non eros interdum venenatis eget quis justo. Cras neque orci, semper eu augue ut, lobortis feugiat lectus. Proin at tincidunt elit. \\

\end{longtable}
\restoregeometry
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Here is my way for landscape https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461683/120578 It possibly works for you too

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @koleygr.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be compatible with longtable.  The first page rotates as desired, but it cuts the table off at the single page (just runs into the bottom margin).  My guess would be minipage not being compatible for multi-page environments.

Comment: Geometry doesn't allow a change of the paper format in mid document. See here for a work around: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/527031/2388

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209685/landscape-mode-and-page-numbering.  i recently developed a pagestyle for pdflscape, but the OP deleted the question and I lost the code.